# void operator()() understanding

Tags: c++, boost-thread

I am learning how to use thread in boost library, during my search I found the code below:

```
struct count
{
    count(int id) : id(id) {}

    void operator()()
    {
         for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
         {
             boost::mutex::scoped_lock
             lock(io_mutex);
             std::cout << id << ": " << i << std::endl;
         }
    }
    int id;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    boost::thread thrd1(count(1));
    boost::thread thrd2(count(2));

    thrd1.join();
    thrd2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

This program works fine, but my question is, what is the behaviour of the `void 
operator()()` function? Because there are two threads and each one initializes the count with different values. It's two main `count` variables are created seperately, so their `void operator()()` should be different for each variable. But it seems that `void operator()()` is the same for both threads. One more thing in this code `void operator()()` is not being called from anywhere, so how it is running?

Can someone please explain me what is going on inside this function?

```
void operator()()
```

Comment: What makes you think they're the same for both threads?

Comment: @JosephMansfield I run this program for checking the working of mutex, and it is showing the exact working of mutex..it is not allowing the other thread to work on this function until first thread complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a tricky syntax here.

```
boost::thread thrd1(count(1));
boost::thread thrd2(count(2));
```

In those two lines, the `operator()` is **NOT** called directly. The `count(n)` visible here is the **constructor**. Then, the objects constructed with '1' and '2' values are passed to a `thread` objects, which then internally calls `operator()` to run the specific task on that different thread created for this purpose.

But since two objects remembered different values (1/2) in their ctors, the common code in `operator()` operates on different actual values of `id` field. That's why the operator has no parameters: all required params are stored in the 'count' object during its construction.

Btw. to construct an object and call the `operator()`, a line would look like this:

```
count(1)();
```

Comment: @JosephMansfield: thanks, I've pasted the op-definition automatically without thinking.

Comment: but why it is calling operator function internally? means if I defined some other function it will not behave the same way..

Comment: When you start a new thread (i.e. with `boost::thread` class), the "thread" must know what job/task/code you want to be run on that thread. You **have** to tell it what you want to be done _somehow_. And the "way of telling" must be general enough, so that you should be able to give it any job you want. Therefore, `boost::thread` _requires_ you to put the job to be done into an operator(). If you adhere to it, then the `boost::thread` can simply take any object you give (i.e. "count" object), create thread, run the well-known operator() form your object, and it's sure that the job will be done

Comment: If you add a new method to the `count` class, for example `doMyJob`, then the `boost::thread` will execute the `operator()`. It will not "see" the extra method. If you want to add that extra method, simply call that method from your `operator()`. I.e. `public: void operator()(){ doMyJob(); }    private: void myJob(){ ..sayBoom..}`

Comment: ok now this point is clear to me, my second point was how thread taking this function same for both the threads? as you explain in your second para of your answer. Could you explain this point also in detail?

Comment: I already told you that. There is ONE code (the 'function' `operator()()`), and ONE class `counter`, but there are TWO objects. First is created/constructed at line `counter(1)`, and second is created/constructed at line `counter(2)`. Those two object share the same layout (class) and the same function (...), but they are separate objects. Note that the class `counter` says that "there is a field `int id;`". Both objects have such field, but they have separate versions of it. First object remembers "1" in its ID field, second object remembers "2" in its ID field.

Comment: Then, when a new-thread runs the function operator() on the first object, the functions "sees" the ID with value 1. And when another new-thread runs the function operator() with **second object**, the functions "sees" the ID with value 2, that from **second object**.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of operator overloading in C++ is :

return-type operator operator-name (args);
Example : int operator+(int other)
Here the operator name is "+". In your case, it's "()"

Now here, you've got 2 instances of thread, each one having it's own instance of count. When the thread calls operator()(), it reads the count value of the particular instance of thread which is why you have different results for the same operator

Answer (score 0):

It would certainly help fi you read the context of the code (and post a link here for other readers :)).

Without any other context to help me, I'd guess this was a demonstration for new learners of boost::thread. I'll assume you know how threads work - [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/6je9h032e/index.html) is a good beginners concepts reference if you're new.

To break it down:

```
    boost::thread thrd1(count(1));
    boost::thread thrd2(count(2));
```

create two threads with different Ids. As @quetzalcoatl mentions, the boost thread takes in a function object that defines the `operator ()()` and executes the contents of that operator in a different thread. This means we have 3 threads now - the main execution thread and the 2 threads that we've created above.

```
    thrd1.join();
    thrd2.join();
```

the main execution thread waits for the other two threads to *join* - i.e. finish their processing and indicate to the main thread that they are done. When they *join* the thread  is terminated (note that thrd1 is a boost thread object - used to reference the actual thread we create behind the scenes, and will be available till the stack ends).

The `operator()()` is a way to monitor a. which thread is running and b. how many '[skipping-between-threads](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~narten/110/nachos/main/node13.html)' happen. Before explaining, let's see the result. It's likely to be something like (but probably not exactly):

```
1: 0
1: 1
2: 0
2: 1
2: 2
2: 3
1: 2 ...
```

So the program (in this case) runs two loops of thread #1, switches to thread #2, runs a few loops, comes back to #1 and continues running. [There is a reason](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section) both threads can't go into the loop at the same time - the boost scoped_lock grabs hold of the (external) io_mutex, locks it down for that thread's use and proceeds to run till the scoped_lock object is destroyed and the io_mutex object released. This means, while both threads are running parallelly, only one object has access to that specific stack after the "scoped_lock" call.

Hope that helps.